# odoo validate by database

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-9

I want to make validation when both field customer_id and project_product_id inserted together and checked with the database and show error if both are the same with the database

My py code is like

```
_name='crm.project'
customer_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner','Customer')
@api.multi 
@api.constrains('customer_id','project_product_id')
def _check_total_value(self):
    target_list = []
    get_customer_id = self.customer_id
    get_project_product_id = self.project_product_id
self.env.cr.execute('''
                            select * 
                            from crm_project 
                            where customer_id = %s 
                                AND project_product_id = %s
                                
    ''',(get_customer_id,get_project_product_id))
    for target in self.env.cr.dictfetchall():
        target_list.append(target)
    if target_list:
        raise Warning("data duplicate")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> checked with the database and show error if both are the same with the database

Then you clearly need a [UNIQUE constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) in your database.

Please **don't check such things in your python code** - there are dozens of cases when something can go wrong, when you're checking data validity in a client application, but not on the database level. [More info](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS).

And that's how to [make a database-level unique constraint in Odoo](https://www.odoo.com/ru_RU/forum/pomoshch-1/unique-multiple-fields-96863)